# How to disable ssl verification for http.client.HTTPSConnection class in python?

Tags: python, ssl, httpclient

In the official doc of *HTTP PROTOCOL CLIENT*

> class http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, port=None, key_file=None,
>   cert_file=None, [timeout, ]source_address=None, *, context=None,
>   check_hostname=None)
>
> A subclass of HTTPConnection that uses SSL for communication with
>   secure servers. Default port is 443. If context is specified, it must
>   be a ssl.SSLContext instance describing the various SSL options.

Is there any option to disable ssl verification like python requests library as `verify=fasle`

For some reasons I can't use *HTTPConnection* class which would be a straight forward solution. I have to use *HTTPSConnection* and work with

`HTTPConnection.putrequest()`

to send request without the ssl verification.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

while creating https connection make sure that you pass context parameter as follows

```
import http.client
import ssl

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(
    HOSTNAME,
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
)
```

Comment: The same is for `urllib.request.urlopen(HOSTNAME, context = ssl._create_unverified_context())` since urllib in Python 3.4.3 (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.request.urlopen)